# Making table headers scroll with page

Tags: html, css

I've got a table:

```
<table class="table">
    <div id="table-header">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </div>
    <tr>
        <td>
            someName
        </td>
        <td>
            someAge
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to make my table headers stick to the top of the page as I scroll when I have more rows. I've tried the following example from w3schools:

```
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the header
var header = document.getElementById("table-header");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        header.classList.add("sticky");
    } else {
        header.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
}
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%
}
```

I feel like I have the logic down, but I'm not sure why this won't work. I'm guessing it has something to do with the CSS?

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: further, how exactly does your javascript come to be called? if it comes before your table creation, it won't know your table exists.

Answer (score 1):

Use `scroll` event handler on `window`, and using another `table` with a fixed position to show the header at the top of the page.

Try this :-

**HTML**

```
<table id="fixed-header"></table>
```

**CSS**

```
#fixed-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px; display:none;
    background-color:white;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var tableOffset = $("#table-1").offset().top;
var $header = $("#table-1 > thead").clone();
var $fixedHeader = $("#fixed-header").append($header);

$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    var offset = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (offset >= tableOffset && $fixedHeader.is(":hidden")) {
        $fixedHeader.show();
    }
    else if (offset < tableOffset) {
        $fixedHeader.hide();
    }
});
```

Working Example : http://jsfiddle.net/fj8wM/9908/

Comment: It would be better if you can explain the code to him :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an working example you can add more content to check it.

```js
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the header
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
/* Style the header */
.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Page content */
.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

/* The sticky class is added to the header with JS when it reaches its scroll position */
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}

/* Add some top padding to the page content to prevent sudden quick movement (as the header gets a new position at the top of the page (position:fixed and top:0) */
.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
    
        <tr class="header" id="myHeader">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td>
            someName
        </td>
        <td>
            someAge
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            someName
        </td>
        <td>
            someAge
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            someName
        </td>
        <td>
            someAge
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            someName
        </td>
        <td>
            someAge
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            someName
        </td>
        <td>
            someAge
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            someName
        </td>
        <td>
            someAge
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            someName
        </td>
        <td>
            someAge
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            someName
        </td>
        <td>
            someAge
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            someName
        </td>
        <td>
            someAge
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            someName
        </td>
        <td>
            someAge
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            someName
        </td>
        <td>
            someAge
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            someName
        </td>
        <td>
            someAge
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            someName
        </td>
        <td>
            someAge
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            someName
        </td>
        <td>
            someAge
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            someName
        </td>
        <td>
            someAge
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            someName
        </td>
        <td>
            someAge
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            someName
        </td>
        <td>
            someAge
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            someName
        </td>
        <td>
            someAge
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            someName
        </td>
        <td>
            someAge
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            someName
        </td>
        <td>
            someAge
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            someName
        </td>
        <td>
            someAge
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            someName
        </td>
        <td>
            someAge
        </td>
    </tr>
  
</table>
```